# Load image from file in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

So I have my Javascript code that I've included in my HTML file:

```
<script>
var checkbox = document.getElementById('checkbox');
var checkbox_1 = document.getElementById('checkbox_1');
var checkbox_2 = document.getElementById('checkbox_2');

var img_1 = "green.png";
var img_2 = "red.png";
var img_3 = "yellow.png";

checkbox.onclick = function () {
    if (checkbox.src == img_1) {
        checkbox.src = img_2;
    } else if (checkbox.src == img_2) {
        checkbox.src = img_3;
    } else if (checkbox.src == img_3) {
        checkbox.src = img_1;
    }
}
checkbox_1.onclick = function () {
    if (checkbox_1.src == img_1) {
        checkbox_1.src = img_2;
    } else if (checkbox_1.src == img_2) {
        checkbox_1.src = img_3;
    } else if (checkbox_1.src == img_3) {
        checkbox_1.src = img_1;
    }
}
checkbox_2.onclick = function () {
    if (checkbox_2.src == img_1) {
        checkbox_2.src = img_2;
    } else if (checkbox_2.src == img_2) {
        checkbox_2.src = img_3;
    } else if (checkbox_2.src == img_3) {
        checkbox_2.src = img_1;
    }
}
</script>
```

What I want to do, is load the images from file, not from URL. From URL, it works fine, but from file it doesn't. Why is that, and how can I fix it?

Comment: The file-system can't be accessed via javascript in the browser. But you could make the user select a file via an `input` element if that satisfies your needs.

Comment: You can access files, but the user needs to initiate that access (for obvious security reasons).  This is a good place to start: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications

Comment: `input type="checkbox"`  elements do not have a `src` attribute. You probably need to use the `value` attrubute instead.

Comment: On the html did you set anything to the src?

Comment: Could you show your html?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on where those image files are. If those images are in the same directory as the HTML file is, it should work or

```
var img_1 = "./green.png";
var img_2 = "./red.png";
var img_3 = "./yellow.png";
```

Otherwise, you should say where they are with their names. For example, if your web directory structure is as follows,

```
.- index.html
 ㄴ img
     ㄴ green.png
     ㄴ red.png
     ㄴ yellow.png
```

then your image variables should be like

```
var img_1 = "/img/green.png";
var img_2 = "/img/red.png";
var img_3 = "/img/yellow.png";
```

Answer (score 1):

On my point of view, this may be happening because you didn't set in the html the `src` attribute, if you what to do that in Javascript, you should do something add like this (remember to put the images in the same folder as the html):

```
checkbox.src = img_1;
checkbox_1.src = img_2;
checkbox_2.src = img_3;
```

But if you are having problems changing the already existent picture that's because when you give an object the src attribute it takes the whole path, e.g ".\img.png" => "C:\Users\User\documents\website\img.png".
So try something like this:

```
if (checkbox.src.split("/")[checkbox.src.split("/").length - 1]) {
```

Or if you want something more clean:

```
var array_path = checkbox.src.split("/");
if(array_path[array_path.length - 1]){
```